# customized week label in org-mode agenda view

Tags: org-mode, org-agenda

Is it possible for org-mode agenda view to display a customized label for the week, in addition to the week number included by default? For example, the agenda for the current week shows:

```
Week-agenda (W37):
Monday      9 September 2019 W37
```

Instead, I would like it to show one of the following options, or a similar one (no preference, other than ease of implementation):

```
Week-agenda (W37 | A W00):
Monday      9 September 2019 W37 | A W00
```

```
Week-agenda (W37):
Monday      9 September 2019 W37 | A W00
```

```
Week-agenda (W37 | A W00):
Monday      9 September 2019 W37
```

The custom label captures one of three periods in the year (A--C), each comprising 10 weeks (W00--W10). The start date for each period is arbitrary, so it has to be set manually.

Comment: I am looking for something similar, since at my workplace they use a specific week system which does not match the week numbering system advocated by org-mode agenda. Therefore, I would like to have a display of a different week number which I could set manually.

Comment: I would like something similar too, I use with my students a specific week system which does not match the week numbering in the year calendar. Therefore, I would like to have a display of a different week number which I could customize.

Answer (score 0):

I believe the answer is 'no'. However, you can create a property on the org files that contains the custom week number and then create a customized org agenda view based on a search for that property. This view can be saved as a custom command in `org-agenda-custom-commands`.