# Modify emacs calendar starting week number

Tags: org-mode, calendar

I want to change emacs default calendar week number so that it starts at a manually preset date.
Normally the year is broken into 52 weeks and week 1 is the one that contains the 1st of January. I'd like to be able to either change this date to another, 20 of July (say), or to have a second week number that gets displayed when org-agenda is called. Like so

```
Week-agenda (W01):
Monday     20 July 2020 W01
Tuesday    21 July 2020
Wednesday  22 July 2020
Thursday   23 July 2020
Friday     24 July 2020
Saturday   25 July 2020
Sunday     26 July 2020
```

or

```
Week-agenda (W30 | W01):
Monday     20 July 2020 W30 | W01
Tuesday    21 July 2020
Wednesday  22 July 2020
Thursday   23 July 2020
Friday     24 July 2020
Saturday   25 July 2020
Sunday     26 July 2020
```

These are the closest posts that I could find so far [link1](https://emacs.stackexchange.com/questions/52604/customized-week-label-in-org-mode-agenda-view) [link2](https://www.emacswiki.org/emacs/CalendarWeekNumbers). I am using emacs 26.3 and org 9.2.6. This question is relevant because at my work place the week system is offset from the normal week system, and it would be great to be able to adjust emacs to it.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Looking at the souce code reveals that Org uses calendar functions to calculate that. You need to change `calendar-iso-from-absolute`.

Try the following modification, this will affect the calendar's week calculation and with that org-mode's. You can see the result, if you activate [calendars week number view](https://www.emacswiki.org/emacs/CalendarWeekNumbers).

```el
    (defun calendar-iso-from-absolute (date)
      (let* ((approx (calendar-extract-year
                      (calendar-gregorian-from-absolute (+ date 2))))
             (year (+ approx
                      (calendar-sum y approx
                                    (>= date (calendar-iso-to-absolute
                                              (list 1 1 (1+ y))))
                                    1)))
             (weekstart (calendar-absolute-from-gregorian (list 7 (+ 20 2) year))))
        (list
         (1+ (/ (- date (if (> weekstart date)
                            (calendar-absolute-from-gregorian (list 7 (+ 20 2) (- year 1)))
                          weekstart))
                7))
         (% date 7)
         year)))
```

The function above needs some minor tweaking to get it 100% correct.
I do not know why the date needs to be 3 days less, I just took it over from the `approx` calculation at the beginning of this function.

Of course you could also write an `advice` `:after` for the function above and then modify the `car` of its result list.

*Edit to answer comment:* to activate it from within your init, this function needs to be redefined, after the original version has been loaded. To do so you can put this new function definition in the `:config` part of `(use-package cal-iso ...`

```el
    (use-package cal-iso
      :defer t
      :config
      (defun calendar-iso-from-absolute (date)
        ...
        )
      )
```

or you could use

```el
(with-eval-after-load "cal-iso"
   (defun calendar-iso-from-absolute (date)
      ...
    ))
```

because `calendar-iso-from-absolute` is defined in file `cal-iso.el`.

Or, better yet, override it via `advice` (thanks to Basil). Note: you have to give your own function a different name.

```el
(defun my-calendar-iso-from-absolute (date)
  ...
  )
(advice-add #'calendar-iso-from-absolute :override #'my-calendar-iso-from-absolute)
```

Comment: Thanks @jue. I've made some edits to change the month and the offset of number of days (had to be +2 for some reason). I think that this has to do with the definition of the ISO week date described in the function documentation. One question remains though... How can I activate the function in init.el? Probably because it is a compiled function it does not load automatically (i've got to do it manually).

Comment: @Andre please see my edit

Comment: Instead of redefining a function after its package has been loaded, I find it better to add an `:override` advice on the corresponding symbol using either `define-advice` or `advice-add`. This has several advantages: 1) the advice can be defined before its target function has been defined, i.e. at the top-level of your `user-init-file`; 2) the advice can easily be disabled and reenabled again, for debugging purposes; 3) the advice is listed in the `*Help*` buffer for its target function.

Comment: @Basil thanks, til

Comment: BTW if you use the `define-advice` macro in Emacs 25+ (instead of the lower-level `advice-add`, it will generate the advice function name for you.

Comment: Brilliant. I've tried lots of commands but I wouldn't get to `define-advice` or `advice-add` on my own - it's too much for my limited knowledge on elisp. Thank you very much to both.

Answer (score 1):

I'm afraid override `calendar-iso-from-absolute` is not a good idea, it will mess thing up.
The line "Week-agenda (W01):" is generated by `org-agenda-list`, but it will generate something like "Week-agenda (W01-w04):" due to the different view (month view, for example). So this line is not suitable for modifying.
The other line "Monday     11 April 2022 W15" is generated by `org-agenda-format-date-aligned`, it is suitable to attach additional information.

```lisp
(defun org-days-to-relative-week (days-now days-start)
  "Compute weeks between two date.
DAYS-NOW and DAYS-START are both days from absolute gregorian"
  (1+ (/ (- days-now days-start) 7)))
(defun my-org-agenda-format-date-aligned (orig-fun date)
  (let ((day-of-week (calendar-day-of-week date))
    (custom-week (org-days-to-relative-week
              (calendar-absolute-from-gregorian date)
              (calendar-absolute-from-gregorian '(2 28 2002))))
    (orig-str (funcall orig-fun date)))
    (if (and custom-week (= 1 day-of-week))
    (format "%s | Week %02d" orig-str custom-week)
      orig-str)))
(advice-add 'org-agenda-format-date-aligned :around #'my-org-agenda-format-date-aligned)
```

Comment: Thanks, I've made some edits to your answer, as it was throwing an error out.